# How do I run Multiple commands for every x seconds

Tags: shell-script, ssh, firewall

I need help in creating a script that i can run by ssh into below firewall ip for every ten seconds from a linux machine. I have to save all the commands output to a file that is readable

Firewall ip: 10.121.8.100

**these two run only one time (first time)**

```
set cli pager off
set cli scripting-mode on
```

**these four commands should run in the below order for every ten seconds**

```
show running resource-monitor ingress-backlogs
show running resource-monitor second last 10
show session info
show counter global filter delta yes
```

Comment: Please post here any code that you have tried so far.

Comment: i have the script for teraterm but unfortunately i cant use that application

Answer (score 0):

Use an endless `while` loop with a `sleep`.

```
set cli pager off
set cli scripting-mode on
while true; do
  show running resource-monitor ingress-backlogs;
  show running resource-monitor second last 10;
  show session info;
  show counter global filter delta yes;
  sleep 10;
done
```

Comment: thank for your response but how do i ssh into my firewall, there should be some line like "ssh user@1.1.1.1 password" in the script right??

Answer (score -1):

Below script will work for your scenario

```
ssh serverip <<'EOF'
set cli pager off
set cli scripting-mode on
for ((i=1;i>=1;i++))
do
show running resource-monitor ingress-backlogs
sleep 10
show running resource-monitor second last 10
sleep 10
show session info
sleep 10
show counter global filter delta yes
sleep 10
done
EOF
```